# Finding the minimum in an array (but skipping some elements) using reduction in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, reduce, minimum

I have a large array of floating point numbers and I want to find out the minimum value of the array (ignoring `-1`s wherever present) as well as its index, using reduction in CUDA. I have written the following code to do this, which in my opinion should work:

```
 __global__ void get_min_cost(float *d_Cost,int n,int *last_block_number,int *number_in_last_block,int *d_index){
     int tid = threadIdx.x;
     int myid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
     int s;

     if(result == (*last_block_number)-1){
         s = (*number_in_last_block)/2;
     }else{
         s = 1024/2;
     }

     for(;s>0;s/=2){
         if(myid+s>=n)
             continue;
         if(tid<s){
             if(d_Cost[myid+s] == -1){
                 continue;
             }else if(d_Cost[myid] == -1 && d_Cost[myid+s] != -1){
                 d_Cost[myid] = d_Cost[myid+s];
                 d_index[myid] = d_index[myid+s];
             }else{
                 // both not -1
                 if(d_Cost[myid]<=d_Cost[myid+s])
                     continue;
                 else{
                     d_Cost[myid] = d_Cost[myid+s];
                     d_index[myid] = d_index[myid+s];
                 }
             }
         }
         else
             continue;
         __syncthreads();
     }
     if(tid==0){
         d_Cost[blockIdx.x] = d_Cost[myid];
         d_index[blockIdx.x] = d_index[myid];
     }
     return;
 }
```

The `last_block_number` argument is the id of the last block, and `number_in_last_block` is the number of elements in last block (which is a power of `2`). Thus, all blocks will launch `1024` threads every time and the last block will only use `number_in_last_block` threads, while others will use `1024` threads.

After this function runs, I expect the minimum values for each block to be in `d_Cost[blockIdx.x]` and their indices in `d_index[blockIdx.x]`.

I call this function multiple times, each time updating the number of threads and blocks. The second time I call this function, the number of threads now become equal to the number of blocks remaining etc.

However, the above function isn't giving me the desired output. In fact, it gives a different output every time I run the program, i.e, it returns an incorrect value as the minimum during some intermediate iteration (though that incorrect value is quite close to the minimum every time).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable code, not just the kernel.  Also, please don't use line numbers this way. It makes it difficult for someone else to try to compile your code.

Comment: Unless you are not doing this job for educational purposes, perhaps using Thrust would be recommendable.

Comment: I wasn't really aware of this library, thanks for introducing me to it . But I feel that I should still implement this on my own as I'm going to need a lot of customizations later.

Comment: Some threads skip the call to `__syncthreads()` in the for loop due to the continue statements.  Is that intentional?  That probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Large blocks of code are less likely to get responses.  You could simplify the kernel and explain the intended pattern of memory references performed by the kernel.

Comment: @Heatsink I never thought about the continue statements. I'll check on that, and get back. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I would recommend to avoid writing reductions of your own and use CUDA Thrust whenever possible. This holds true even in the case when you need to customize those operations, the customization being possible by properly overloading, e.g., relational operations.

Below I'm providing a simple code to evaluate the minimum in an array along with its index. It is based on a classical example contained in the [An Introduction to Thrust](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/downloads/detail?name=An%20Introduction%20To%20Thrust.pdf) presentation. The only addition is skipping, as you requested, the `-1`'s from the counting. This can be reasonably done by replacing all the `-1`'s in the array by `INT_MAX`, i.e., the maximum representable integer according to IEEE floating point standards.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\replace.h>
#include <thrust\sequence.h>
#include <thrust\reduce.h>
#include <thrust\iterator\zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust\tuple.h>

// --- Struct returning the smallest of two tuples
struct smaller_tuple
{
    __host__ __device__ thrust::tuple<int,int> operator()(thrust::tuple<int,int> a, thrust::tuple<int,int> b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;
    }
};


void main() {

    const int N = 20;
    const int large_value = INT_MAX;

    // --- Setting the data vector
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(N,10);
    d_vec[3] = -1; d_vec[5] = -2;

    // --- Copying the data vector to a new vector where the -1's are changed to FLT_MAX
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec_temp(d_vec);
    thrust::replace(d_vec_temp.begin(), d_vec_temp.end(), -1, large_value);

    // --- Creating the index sequence [0, 1, 2, ... )
    thrust::device_vector<int> indices(d_vec_temp.size());
    thrust::sequence(indices.begin(), indices.end());

    // --- Setting the initial value of the search
    thrust::tuple<int,int> init(d_vec_temp[0],0);

    thrust::tuple<int,int> smallest;
    smallest = thrust::reduce(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_vec_temp.begin(), indices.begin())),
                          thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_vec_temp.end(), indices.end())),
                          init, smaller_tuple());

    printf("Smallest %i %i\n",thrust::get<0>(smallest),thrust::get<1>(smallest));
    getchar();
}
```