# Minimum in vector, skipping some indices

Tags: algorithm, c++11, minimum

I have a vector of doubles and need to know the index and value of the minimum value in the vector. This is easy done with the algorithm header, however I need to ignore some indices.

Just removing the indices is not working since I need the original index. Another option is to add a constant to all values which has to be skipped such that they are for sure not the minimum. However this seems very inefficient.

At the moment I have the following function in which I still have to skip the indices given in `except`. I try to find the *minimum* of `d_distance`.

```
pair<size_t, double> City::closest(vector<size_t> const &except) const
{ 
  auto min_el = min_element(d_distance.begin(), d_distance.end());
  size_t idx = distance(d_distance.begin(), min_el) + 1;

  return make_pair(idx, *min_el);
}
```

Note that my question is different then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761218/finding-the-minimum-in-an-array-but-skipping-some-elements-using-reduction-in) since he wants to skip certain values rather than indices.

Comment: Looks a bit like you're trying to make a poor man's graph algorithm. Don't fight it: graphs are nice. Vertex coloring is the mechanism you seem to be emulating here.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly iterate through your vector and ignore the indexes. Here is how it can be done:

```
std::pair<size_t, double> closest(
   std::vector<double> const & distance, 
   std::vector<size_t> const & except)
{
   auto min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
   auto pos = static_cast<size_t>(-1);

   auto pos_except = size_t{0};
   for(size_t i = 0; i < distance.size(); ++i)
   {
      if(pos_except < except.size() && i == except[pos_except])
         pos_except++;
      else
      {
         if(distance[i] < min)
         {
            min = distance[i];
            pos = i;
         }
      }
   }

   return std::make_pair(pos, min);
}

int main()
{
   auto distance = std::vector<double> {10.0, 2.5, 0.5, 4.5, 8.0, 17.2, 10.1};
   auto except = std::vector<size_t> {0, 2, 5};

   auto result = closest(distance, except);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: instead of omitting the documentation that `except` **must** be sorted ascending, you could just use a `std::set<size_t>` instead and be done...